# How to create layount elements depending on data context in protovis-js?

Tags: javascript, protovis

I look at this [beautiful sample and its so](http://mbostock.github.io/protovis/ex/antibiotics-burtin.html) and can't help but wonder how to create lemements like:

```
bg.add(pv.Wedge)
          .angle(smallAngle)
          .startAngle(function(d) this.proto.startAngle() + smallAngle)
          .outerRadius(function(d) radius(d.penicillin))
          .fillStyle(drugColor.Penicillin)
```

only if `d.penicillin > 0` then call  `bg.add(pv.Wedge)` (so have more or less ui elements depending on data, not only its params)?